# Why do techno artists add noise to recordings?

Tags: vinyl, techno

First I thought that there was something wrong with the record, but if you listen to the track "Hiroshi Kano" by the artist Viers, then there is noise in the track on purpose (?) and the same for the track "It's all good" by Alex K in the beginning. Is it really the artists adding noise on purpose because first I thought that it was something wrong with the vinyl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brain perceives rhythmic patterns in an enjoyable, or at least attentive manner.

This effect was used long before techno in experiments by Steve Reich, most famous [It's Gonna Rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Gonna_Rain)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vugqRAX7xQE

Answer (score 2):

All instrument sounds can be characterized by the sum of what are called harmonic and stochastic components.

Harmonic components of a sound are predominant in pitched instruments, they are what gives us a "note" being played by an instrument.

Stochastic componentes are what we normally would call "noise" and are stronger in percussion instruments, and predominant in non tuned ones, but also exist to a certain extent in pitched instruments, specially in the initial onset ("attack") of each note.

When synthesizing sounds, musicians or sound designers "play" with these two components to create the sound the desire, either to emulate a real instrument or natural sound as close as possible, or to create new sounds in a creative way. For example, a very basic "drum" synthesized sound could be made with just a simple sinusoidal wave quickly decaying, with a burst of some white noise added.

Sometimes, to emphasize the artificial nature of a sound or to give a more percussive element to a melodic musical component, the stochastic element can be exagerated, even to the point of becoming dominant.

As pointed out by Dalv Olan, this has been hapenning since there has been "electronic" music. Other notable examples come from the German electronic music of the 60's and 70's (e.g. bands like Tangerine Dream and, specially, Krafwerk), were a noise element was frequently added to synthesizer melodic sounds to enhance the rythmic element of the music. Some example can also be found the synth pop scene of the 80's.

In the case of the artists mentioned in the question, the occasional strong noise element creatively integrated in the music (it need not be just added noise, but interacting with the overall synthetic sounds as explained above), helps the music to convey a technological and artificial (i.e. non natural) feeling which, I believe, is part of the aesthetical values of the artists.